# Plotly opens prompt screen after drawing plot

Tags: python, plotly

I use the following code to draw a heatmap in `plotly`:

```
import plotly.offline as plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as graph_objs

x = []
# fill x with stuff
path = os.path.join(self.get_current_job_directory(), track + '.html')
trace = graph_objs.Heatmap(z = x)
data = [trace]
plotly.plot(data, filename = path)
```

But I get a prompt screen like this. I need to generate hundreds of such plots on a remote server and its not practical to just dismiss them.

[image]

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `filename` argument tells Plotly what filename to use for the HTML file it generates to contain the plot. That file is then viewed in the system's default HTML viewer, which in this case appears to be Lynx. Of course that's rather useless as the point is to view the plot, and Lynx is a text-only Web browser!

To avoid opening the plot, add `auto_open=False` to your `plot()` call:

```
plotly.plot(data, filename=path, auto_open=False)
```